# jquery autocomplete by one key on multiple fields with same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery.autocomplete for searching items by code and autocomplete the code and also update previous form input field called name:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Name[]" class="nameautoc" value="badname1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Code[]" class="codeautoc" value="1234" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Name[]" class="nameautoc" value="ok_name" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Code[]" class="codeautoc" value="12345" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Name[]" class="nameautoc" value="badname2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Code[]" class="codeautoc" value="34567" /></td>
</tr>
```

The autocomplet by the code itself works ok, for each Code input field.
When added the JS code to update the matching Name field, it update the whole form Name fields instead of the previous/or the current one I'm working on.

How can I implement that only the current input Name field is autocompleted by the code I choose, or should I use JS code refering to the table I'm using?

The JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function($) { 
        $(".codeautoc").autocomplete({
            source:"codenName.php",
            minLength:2,
            select:function(event,ui){
                var item=ui.item;
                if(item){
                    $(".nameautoc").val(item.name);
                }
            }
    });
```

The relevant PHP code:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $return_row['label'] = $row['code'];
        $return_row['value'] = $row['code'];
        $return_row['name'] = $row['name'];
        array_push($return_arr, $return_row);
    }
```

Hope I provided the needed information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` callback should look something like this:

```
  select:function(event,ui){
      var item=ui.item;
      if(item){
         $(".nameautoc", $(this).parents('tr')).val(item.name);
      }
  }
```

By adding `$(this).parents('tr')` as context in the jquery selector (Refer to [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) for more details), you're making sure that only the matching child elements of the parent `tr` element are updated, instead of all elements with class `nameautoc` in the document.

Optionally, you can also use `$(this).parent().parent()` to traverse upto the `tr`, instead of using `$(this).parents('tr')`. [Here's the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fCs7W/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, it didn't helped no matter what I tried. I also updated my question (the html table) with the right table formatting I missed before, sorry and thanks again.

Comment: Still, same issues, all input fields named name="Name[]" with class name "nameautoc" are updated. even your example code does that. maybe it is the fact I'm using jquery 1.10.4?

Comment: Using your second suggestion, $(this).parent().parent() did the trick! Many thanks for your help, prompt response, examples and detailed answer. David

Comment: @DavidPeer The first suggestion would work correctly if the HTML code that you've provided isn't wrapped around by another table and tr tag. $(this).parents('tr') would return all the parent tr items, which could lead incorrect results(all input boxes updated) if there are other wrapper tables in your DOM. JQuery version shouldn't be an issue, imo.